# How to check a method as long as the app is open

Tags: android

For example, I want to check if wifi is enabled forever . If it is enabled my button will turn on, if it is off my button will turn off, but when I use my method(I will provide it) it only checks once when the app is created, but I want it to check as long as possible until the phone is turned off or the process it killed, if someone could help that would be great!

Wifi Check Method:

```
  public void checkWifi() {

    WifiManager wifim = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    ToggleButton wifi=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.wifibutton);

    if (wifim.getWifiState()==(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED)) {

        wifi.setChecked(true);

    } else {

...

}
```

Comment: An Android app never "closes", any more than a Web app "closes". Please redefine your problem to something that is amenable to the architecture.

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the state of wifi on create, and register a broadcast receiver to listen to changes, and if WIFI goes off, change your state.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Handle receiver

            ConnectivityManager mConnectivity;
            mConnectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo info = mConnectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (info == null || !mConnectivity.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
                //CHANGE YOUR BUTTON HERE BECAUSE THERE IS NO NETWORK AT ALL
                return;
            } else {
                int netType = info.getType();
                int netSubtype = info.getSubtype();
                if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    //CHANGE YOUR BUTTON HERE BECAUSE THERE IS WIFI

                } else {
                    //CHANGE YOUR BUTTON HERE BECAUSE THERE IS NETWORK BUT ITS NOT WIFI
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: How could I use this thought to listen and broadcast, as you can see, I am new to Broadcaster and receivers